# Подскажите как сделать чтобы можно было вводить данные с консоли с учетом конструкора, в плане что могут быть незаполненные поля?

Tags: java

После запуска пишу в консоли первую строку но переходя на следующую строку выдает ошибку, подскажите кто в курсе что сделать?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class User {
    String name;
    short age;
    int height;

    public User() {
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.age = a.nextShort();
    
        user1.height = a.nextInt();
       
        user1.name = a.nextLine();
        System.out.println("имя пользователя - " + user1.name +
                "возраст - " + user1.age +
                "рост - " + user1.height);
    }
}
```

---

Вот что выдает консоль

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:947)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextShort(Scanner.java:2127)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextShort(Scanner.java:2081)
    at User.main(User.java:16)
```

Comment: Читать ошибку, что же ещё.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/); [Не сканируется строка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345986/); [Не считывает количество тестов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1505851/)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Scanner не считывает строку после nextInt()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526818/scanner-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-nextint)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы обработать исключение InputMismatchException можете воспользоваться try/catch блоком. Так же чтобы сработало ввод имени пользователя, вам нужно дополнительно очистить буфер после считывания чисел.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        User user = new User();
        try {
        System.out.print("Введите возраст: ");
        short age = a.nextShort();

        System.out.print("Введите рост: ");
        int height = a.nextInt();

        a.nextLine(); // Очистка буфера после считывания чисел

        System.out.print("Введите имя (опционально): ");
        String name = a.nextLine();

        user = new User(name,age,height);
        
        System.out.println("имя пользователя - " + user.name +
                ", возраст - " + user.age +
                ", рост - " + user.height);

        }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("В следующий раз введите корректное значение");
        }

        
    }
```